# How to modify s2p file of an IC? - ADS

Tags: simulation, transient, model, s-parameters, ads

I have a s2p file of a RF IC which it contains frequency from 650 MHz to 1.1 GHz. I wish to modify s2p model so that two frequency 0 Hz and about 3.5 MHz is added to the s2p file.

How can I do that with this s2p file?

I have uploaded the link to the s2p file. I hope it help:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-14AaWDRX0N2Vvq1fp6q9SZ-V_yUWSeT/view?usp=drivesdk

Another point to mention is that I have the large signal model too. But, it takes a lot of time to do transient simulation. So I hope doing transient simulation using s2p file decreases the number of connections in my schematic environment and therefore, simulation is done much more faster.

Comment: Hi! What have you tried? Opening an S2P file in a text editor would be the first step, and I bet it would also be an answer.

Comment: Hello @MarcusMüller, the question is how can I determine s-parameter for a specific frequency may be using large-signal model.

Comment: but: you're trying to simulate frequencies for which your S2P file contains no data, how should it be possible to help that simulation?

Comment: (I understand that you're hoping to avoid most of the transient response calculation by using what's already there, because, well, you don't need to calculate it again, but, that's not going to help your calculation for other frequencies, since transient response is typically done in time domain.)

Comment: Hello @MarcusMüller, 
the following video may clarify the situation:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STCwi7RSn2c&list=WL&index=2

I just want to know s-parameter coefficients in those undefined frequencies and then add the to the former s2p file and finally, I do simulation. above video represents that s2p file even help in this situation. that's it.

Comment: hey, thanks! I will watch it later today.